# Wordpress blank page issue when try to update the post

Tags: wordpress

When I try to update the post or add the post, it take much time to process the request, finally it gave a blank page.

Comment: That information isn't enough.

Comment: My problem is I can't able to update or add the post.

Comment: Step one is to check the server’s error log, to see what is going on. You’re likely running into the PHP max_execution_time for some reason.

Comment: I checked error log nothing is there related to post issue. I set maximum execution time 0 as well maximum input time also. Any how thanks for your response

Comment: Did you disable all the plugins and changed the theme?

Comment: Yes I tried, even I removed all the plugins from plugins directory but no luck

Comment: This might be a problem with memory_limit being set too low. Try to increase memory limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found that, it was caused by fantastic elasticSearch plugin.
Everything is working fine once we deactivate this plugin.